# Using @Repository-style exception translation from Spring Java configuration

Tags: spring, repository

If I want to declare a bean using Spring 3's Java-based configuration, I can do this:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public MyRepository myRepository() {
        return new MyJpaRepository();
    }
}
```

But, since I can't use the `@Repository` annotation in this context, how do get Spring to perform exception translation?

Comment: Why can't you use `@Repository`? Could you use a different annotation instead?

Comment: Because that would create the component from Spring's annotation scanner, not from my configuration class.

Comment: @hertzspring: In that case, reconfigure the scanner not to pick up your class. The scanner can be given include/exclude rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare your MyJpaRepository class as a repository:

```
@Repository
public class MyJpaRepository {
  ...
}
```

And make sure you have your annotations discoverable by setting up the component-scan element in your Spring configuration:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.example.repository"/>
```

Since you do not want your repository included in the annotation scan per your comments, filter it out either by excluding all @Repository annotations or your particular class(es) or package. There is an example of this in the documentation:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.example.repository">
  <!-- use one or the other of these excludes, or both if you *really* want to -->
  <context:exclude-filter type="regex" expression="*Repository"/>
  <context:exclude-filter type="annotation"
                          expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Repository"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

The [Spring 3.0 documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html) describes this configuration in more detail in section 3.10.

By configuring your class as a Repository, it will be designated as one when you pull it out as a Bean in your Configuration class.

Comment: Yup, looks like the `PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor` will find Java-configured as well as annotation-configured beans.  I've ended up using my own custom annotation, `@JavaConfiguredRepository`, and I've added another PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor and overridden its repositoryAnnotationType property.